# Used JSON to format list view: why is my tile view in web part rendering wider than in the list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I am using JSON to format list view in SharePoint online list. Why is my tile view in web part on site pages rendering wider than in the default list page?

A related question: How can I change the height of the Cover section (cover is an image). Warning: I am a newbie to JSON. Here is my JSON code (modified from existing SharePoint code):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 360,
  "width": 250,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "a",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton",
          "role": "presentation",
          "href": "[$Link]"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-previewColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-card-imageContainer"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight sp-card-imagePreviewBackground"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "img",
                        "style": {
                          "display": "=if([$Cover] == '', 'none', '')"
                        },
                        "attributes": {
                          "src": "=getThumbnailImage([$Cover], 400, 400)",
                          "title": "[$Cover.fileName]",
                          "class": "sp-card-imagePreview"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Title]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent",
                  "role": "heading",
                  "aria-level": "3"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Title] == '', '–', [$Title])"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$Notes]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content  sp-card-multiline",
                  "width": 250
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$Notes] == '', '–', [$Notes])",
                "style": {
                  "height": 150,
                  "word-break": "normal"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: SharePoint modern pages are responsive by design. I think because of this SharePoint tries to fit the tiles in column/section layout you have used in your SharePoint page hence tiles are looking wider.

Comment: Thank @GaneshSanap, I thought that might be the case. I wanted to verify that I wasn't missing something in my coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint online modern pages are responsive by design. I think because of this behavior SharePoint tries to fit the tiles in column/section layout you have used in your SharePoint page hence tiles are looking wider in web part on a site page than in the default list page.

For increasing height of image, you can try adding height to style property in `img` element like:

```
"style": {
    "height": "500px",
    "width": "500px"
}
```

Or try to get the thumbnail with bigger size using `getThumbnailImage` operator in `src` property like:

```
"src": "=getThumbnailImage([$Cover], 500, 500)",
```

In case of image size is bigger than tile size, you might need to increase the width (250) / height (360) of the tile.